Remove Quotes When Pasting From A Formula
Like in this simple example on Google Sheet I have a formula to create an official note we add on invoices in QuickBooks which is a concatenation of cells and words.

The formula on cell C1 will show the result below:

This works as intended except that when I copy cell C1 and paste on an invoice on Quickbooks it always includes the double qoutes before the word CASE and after the word RESOLVED. Is there a way to exclude this from the result? I tried changing CHAR(10) to CHAR(13) but it doesn't help, this seem to work fine when pasting on a Gmail email but not on other forms like a Quickbooks Invoice.

This question is similar to: Why does copying multi-row text from Google Sheets to the Instagram caption box add a quote mark at the beginning and end of the text?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hi Tedinoz, yes similar case, I didn't see that. The topic didn't solve my case but the situation is identical

Use CHAR(13) instead of CHAR(10). Try below formula and then copy paste cell data.
="Case Today:"&CHAR(13)&A1&Char(13)&"Status: "&B1


This answer is 100% correct but may not seem so at first. The output of the cell will appear as Case Today: Defective Water Fountain Status: Resolved - all on one line. But when it is copied and pasted (to QuickBooks, or an editor), the output will appear as expected (on three lines).
